# Converting our own OAuth 2 code from the legacy people API to the new people API

Tags: google-people-api

We have a web site that uses the google people API to let people log in through Google. Back when it was originally written, there was no google supplied API, so we wrote our own (using the legacy google+ OAuth2 documentation).

So, now we have a new website that needs to use google login. And... I can't use the legacy people api for new apps. SO, I need to upgrade to the new people API.

The OAuth stuff seems to work just the same (I log in, get a token, and their email and user_id etc without trouble). However, when I try to get a user's name, the syntax seems to have changed.

I used to go to [https://www.googleapi.com/auth/userinfo.email/[user_id]?fields=displayName,name&access_token=[access](https://www.googleapi.com/auth/userinfo.email/%5Buser_id%5D?fields=displayName,name&access_token=%5Baccess) token]
but this no longer works (I get a 403 forbidden).
I've tried changing to the new api, but I'm getting something wrong about the syntax. Here's what I've tried:
[https://people.googelapi.com/v1/{resourceName=names}/*?access_token=[access](https://people.googelapi.com/v1/%7BresourceName=names%7D/*?access_token=%5Baccess) token]
but this returns a 404.

Anyone know what url I need to go to (and the syntax) to get the user's first and last name?

TIA,
Owen

Answer (score 1):

Never fails. Bang my head on the wall for days, then finally ask the question on stackoverflow and within a few hours I've figured it out.

The new call syntax is:
[https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names&access_token=[access_token]](https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names&access_token=%5Baccess_token%5D)

And a completely new object is returned - so looks like I'm going to have to upgrade all the sites to the new api...

Cheers.

#### Reference:

- [Method: people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)